# Pivot Table type of query in Cypher (in one pass)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-performance

I am trying to perform the following query in one pass but I conclude that it is impossible and would furthermore lead to some form of "nested" structure which is never good news in terms of performance.

I may however be missing something here, so I thought I might ask.

The underlying data structure is a many-to-many relationship between two entities `A<---0:*--->B`

The end goal is to obtain how many times are objects of entity `B` assigned to objects of entity `A` within a specific time interval *as a percentage of total assignments*.

It is exactly this latter part of the question that causes the headache.

Entity `A` contains an `item_date` field
Entity `B` contains an `item_category` field.

The presentation of the results can be expanded to a table whose columns are the distinct `item_date` and rows are the different `item_category` *normalised* counts. I am just mentioning this for clarity, the query does not have to return the results in that exact form.

**My Attempt:**

```
with 12*30*24*3600 as window_length, "1980-1-1" as start_date, 
     "1985-12-31" as end_date 
     unwind range(apoc.date.parse(start_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd"),apoc.date.parse(end_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd"),window_length) as date_step
     match (a:A)<-[r:RELATOB]-(b:B) 
         where apoc.date.parse(a.item_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd")>=date_step and apoc.date.parse(a.item_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd")<(date_step+window_length)
         with window_length, date_step, count(r) as total_count unwind ["code_A", "code_B", "code_C"] as the_code [MATCH THE PATTERN AGAIN TO COUNT SPECIFIC `item_code` this time.
```

I am finding it difficult to express this in one pass because it requires the equivalent of two independent `GROUP BY`-like clauses right after the definition of the graph pattern. You can't express these two in parallel, so you have to unwind them. My worry is that this leads to two evaluations: One for the total count and one for the partial count. The bit I am trying to optimise is some way of re-writing the query so that it does not have to count nodes it has "captured" before but this is very difficult with the implied way the aggregate functions are being applied to a set.

Basically, any attribute that is not an aggregate function becomes the stratification variable. I have to say here that a plain simple double stratification ("Grab everything, produce one level of count by `item_date` produce another level of count by `item_code`) does not work for me because there is NO WAY to control the width of the `window_length`. This means that I cannot compare between two time periods with different rates of assignments of `item_code`s because the time periods are not equal :(

Please note that retrieving the counts of `item_code` and then normalising for the sum of **those** particular codes within a period of time (externally to cypher) would not lead to accurate percentages because the normalisation there would be with respect to **that particular subset** of `item_code` rather than the total.

Is there a way to perform a simultaneous count of `r` within a time period but then (somehow) re-use the already matched `a`,`b` subsets of nodes to now evaluate a partial count of those specific `b`'s that `(b:{item_code:the_code})-[r2:RELATOB]-(a) where a.item_date...`?

If not, then I am going to move to the next fastest thing which is to perform two independent queries (one for the total count, one for the partials) and then do the division externally :/ .

Comment: How I usually proceed with "pivoting" is the following...

      sum(CASE WHEN x = y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result

And then do a couple of these

Comment: Thanks @TomažBratanič, I think I get what this solution looks like. I'd upvote a slightly more involved example.

Comment: @TomažBratanič You take the cookie. If you write this as an answer I will still accept it. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by Tomaz Bratanic in the comment is (I think) along these lines:

```
with 1*30*24*3600 as window_length, 
     "1980-01-01" as start_date, 
     "1985-12-31" as end_date 
     unwind range(apoc.date.parse(start_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd"),apoc.date.parse(end_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd"),window_length) as date_step 
     unwind ["code_A","code_B","code_c"] as the_code 
         match (a:A)<-[r:RELATOB]-(b:B) 
             where apoc.date.parse(a.item_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd")>=date_step and apoc.date.parse(a.item_category,"s","yyyy-MM-dd")<(date_step+window_length) 
         return the_code, date_step, tofloat(sum(case when b.item_category=code then 1 else 0 end)/count(r)) as perc_count order by date_step asc
```

This:

1. Is working
2. It does exactly what I was after (after some minor modifications)
3. It even adds filling in the missing values with zero because of that `ELSE 0` which is effectively forcing a zero even when no count data exists.

But in realistic conditions it is at least 30 seconds slower (**no it is not, please see edit**) than what I am currently using which re-matches. (And no, it is not because of the extra data that is now returned as the missing data are filled in, this is raw query time).

I thought that it might be worth attaching the query plans here:

This is the plan of the *applying the same pattern twice but fast* way of doing it:

[image]

This is the plan of the *performing the count in one pass but slow* way of doing it:

[image]

I might see how does time scales with data in the input later on, maybe the two are scaling at different rates but at this point, the "one-pass" seems to be already slower than the "two-pass" and frankly, I cannot see how it could get any faster with more data. This is already a simple count of 12 months over 3 categories distributed amongst 18k items (approximately).

Hope this might help others too.

**EDIT:**

While I had done this originally, there was another modification that I did not include where the second unwind goes **AFTER** the match. This slashes the time by 20 seconds **below** the "double match" as the unwind affects the return rather than multiple executions of the same query which now becomes:

```
with 1*30*24*3600 as window_length, 
     "1980-01-01" as start_date, 
     "1985-12-31" as end_date 
     unwind range(apoc.date.parse(start_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd"),apoc.date.parse(end_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd"),window_length) as date_step  
         match (a:A)<-[r:RELATOB]-(b:B) 
             where apoc.date.parse(a.item_date,"s","yyyy-MM-dd")>=date_step and apoc.date.parse(a.item_category,"s","yyyy-MM-dd")<(date_step+window_length) 
                 unwind ["code_A","code_B","code_c"] as the_code
         return the_code, date_step, tofloat(sum(case when b.item_category=code then 1 else 0 end)/count(r)) as perc_count order by date_step asc
```

And here is the execution plan for it too:

[image]

Original double match approximately 55790ms, Doing it in one pass (both unwinds BEFORE the match) **82306ms**, Doing it in one pass (second unwind **after** the match) **23461ms**.